# Is this a good way to dispose sql connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, ado.net

I just wrote this. Is this a good way to dispose an open sql connection ? My senior told me that this is the best practice but still I want to make my self sure by asking here.

```
public bool SaveBulkpayment(List<ClsCombinePayment> list)
{
    bool Result = false;
    ClsDatabaseManager Manager = ClsDatabaseManager.InitializeDbManager(Constants.Databases.POSSystem);
    Manager.Open();
    Manager.CreateParameters(10);
    try
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Manager.AddParameters(0, "@Batch", item.Batch);
            Manager.AddParameters(1, "@TransactionDateTime", TransactionDateTime);
            Manager.AddParameters(2, "@BatchNo", BatchNo);
            Manager.AddParameters(3, "@Salary", item.Salary);
            Manager.AddParameters(4, "@EDRRecord_ID", item.EDRRecord_ID);
            Manager.AddParameters(5, "@User_ID", item.User_ID);
            Manager.AddParameters(6, "@Branch_ID", item.Branch_ID);
            Manager.AddParameters(7, "@PafFile_ID", item.PAFFile_ID);

            Manager.AddParameters(8, "@PinCode", item.PinCode);
            Manager.AddParameters(9, "@ifDiff", item.ifDiff);
            Result = Manager.ExecuteNonQuery("usp_SaveBulkPayment").ToBool();
        }
        Manager.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.. in the case of an exception it will not be disposed. Use the `using` in order to do so.

Something like:

```
using(var manager = ClsDatabaseManager.InitializeDbManager(Constants.Databases.POSSystem); Manager.Open())
{
    //Your code
}
```

The `using` which can be used only on objects that implement `IDisposable` make sure that the `Dispose()` method will be called even if there is an exception or a return in the block. It is implemented similar to:

```
public void Using<T>( T input, Action<T> predicate) where T : IDisposable
{
    try
    {
        predicate(input);
    }
    finally
    {
        input.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so can i do it this way like putting dispose in finally block ?

Comment: @Cuckoo - yes but the better practice is to use the using

Comment: ok and incase of Reader.close(), should i leave that it is or also move that to finally ?

Comment: and should i use it before then throw ex or after ?

Comment: About the reader I'm not certain but I'd say it like this: you'll want to implement IDisposable in the case where you access unmanaged resources and so provide a clean and clear way to tell everyone that " I must be properly disposed". For reader.close() if it doesn't have the dispose then it might be that it is fine to leave it for the GC (but again, I'm not sure). In any case if you create it before the try block and want to close it no matter what - ya - have it in the finally

Comment: @Cuckoo - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

An open SQL connection should be disposed as early as possible.

In your code a better way though would be to dispose the SQL connection in a finally block. This way even in case of an exception, the connection will be disposed safely

```
try
{
    //Code         
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Handle exception
}
finally{
    //Dispose the Connection
    Manager.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: True :) which is what the `using` keyword makes sure of :)

Comment: @GiladGreen Ah ok. I didnt know the underlying implementation of using till now. Thanks for that.